# Cordova Visual Studio Plugin for Hybrid app only suppports local HTML files?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, multi-device-hybrid-apps, visual-studio-cordova

I would like to know that **cordova Visual Studio plugin to develop Hybrid mobile App only supports the local HTML web application**?

or is there any other Cordova Visual Studio plugin available to develop hybrid application using ASP.NET MVC applications?

(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675)

Comment: I don't really understand the question? There's a MVC framework called AngularJS which is gaining speed in the development community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova provides Local HTML templates for Hybrid-mobile application development. If we add http://www.google.com in config.xml file, then it will generate URL something like "`file:///android-asset/http://www.google.com`" for android. so we will get network error.

**Solution:**

If we want to load http://www.google.com with Cordova template, load URL like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //Update with your remote URL
        this.document.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
</script>
```

**EDIT 1:** This issue has been resolved with [MDHA CTP 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42675). We can give our `Remote URL in the Config.xml page by editing Startup page`

Comment: Can you provide more information about "Remote URL" in the MDHA CTP 2.0 please?

Answer (score 0):

You can get html page and some other resources you need from everywhere, but you need to set the origin property in config.xml file to allow cross-doman calls for our app,( if this is our question).